# Rsymphony OSX Installation failed

Tags: r, macos, failed-installation, installation-package

I'm trying to install Rsymphony package on R on Mac OSX. I get the following error:

```
install.packages("Rsymphony")
Package which is only available in source form, and may need
  compilation of C/C++/Fortran: 'Rsymphony'
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources?
y/n: y
installing the source package 'Rsymphony'

trying URL 'https://mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/src/contrib/Rsymphony_0.1-21.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 7429 bytes
==================================================
downloaded 7429 bytes

During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
* installing *source* package 'Rsymphony' ...
** package 'Rsymphony' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Cannot find SYMPHONY libraries and headers.
See <https://projects.coin-or.org/SYMPHONY>.
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'Rsymphony'
* removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rsymphony'

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/private/var/folders/0n/03x0y52j51q5fsfm3_g8bc000000gn/T/RtmpL7916v/downloaded_packages'
Warning message:
In install.packages("Rsymphony") :
  installation of package 'Rsymphony' had non-zero exit status
```

This package is required for installing "fPortfolio" package. Any hints on possible solution?

Comment: It is clearly written `Cannot find SYMPHONY libraries and headers.`

Comment: Yes, how to get them?

Comment: Again, read the error message. It is clearly written. Hint: search the line starting with `See <https`.

Answer (score 0):

After try and error, finally I found how to install Rsymphony in OSX

install CoinOR repository for brew in terminal

```
~$ brew tap coin-or-tools/coinor
```

install symphony through brew in terminal

```
~$ brew install symphony
```

install Rsymphony under R command line

```
> install.packages("Rsymphony")
```

Hope this helps ^^

Comment: I would have imagined the last one to be done at the R commandline so it should =probably look like `>install.packages("Rsymphony")` to distinguish from a Terminal console command.

Comment: @smalltown i've installed symphony using homebrew and it runs from the commandline but i'm still getting the error above. any suggestions?